# Updating Ublox module via commandline with file

Tags: gps, usb, nmea

I am looking for a way to update my Ublox receivers via Linux commandline. I am using a ZED-F9P module which is connected via USB to my Linux computer. I made a config file in U-Center but how would I then update the module?

I am able to update the module by using socat and then connecting it to U-Center running on a windows pc. Ive tried to look into ubxtool or pyubx2 but both dont seem to support a file update. I did try to write a small parser to convert my human readable file and update it. But this doesnt seem to properly work.

Any way to go about this?

Thanks

I have tried the ubxtool and pyubx2. Both allow changing of the parameters but do not allow updating from a file.